# Obtain ComputerName during installation via WIX

Tags: wix, computer-name

Is it possible to obtain the ComputerName during installation via the Wix Tool Set? If so, how would you go about this process? I wish to set ComputerName for our SQL Install, so that we won't be forced to create separate installation for each computer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't too clear, but if you have generated an MSI setup with the WiX toolset, and you are asking how to get the installing computer's name at install time, then use the ComputerName property:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368009(v=vs.85).aspx

and typically you'd use it in square brackets, but it would help to know exactly where and how you plan to use the name.